# Wait for one of two elements to appear using By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(),

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

None of the examples I find are using `By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(),`.

I have a synthetic job where there is a possibility of one of two texts to appear. If either one appears, I would like to quit. I want to use an `or` rather than two individual `WebDriverWait`.

My current code for just checking one text, which works is:

`WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "More than 3000 results")]')))`

I have tried the following three, but none one are working. It does not find the text or I get a syntax error in the first example.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.or(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "More than 3000 results")]')),
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "The search returned zero results")]'))
    ));
```

`WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "More than 3000 results")]', '//*[contains(text(), "The search returned zero results")]')))`

`WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "More than 3000 results")]')) or ((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "The search returned zero results")]')))`

If I can get it to work, I'll wrap it in a `Try/Except` with a `driver.quit()` in the `Try`.

Below are additional questions I was asked:

I provided three examples of things I tried. Only the first example displays a syntax error. Second and third examples simply do not see any of the two messages and the script just continues on.

This is the syntax error:

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Github\appd-selenium-scripts\Prod>  & 'python' 'c:\Users\uswarv41\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.6.91350\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '63733' '--' 'c:\Github\appd-selenium-scripts\Prod\Claims_CC_PROD_Document_Integration_Validation_Synthetic_Script.py'
  File "c:\Github\appd-selenium-scripts\Prod\Claims_CC_PROD_Document_Integration_Validation_Synthetic_Script.py", line 271
    WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.or(
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
PS C:\Github\appd-selenium-scripts\Prod>
```

Both of the following work on their own, which is why I want to find the right way to use `or`

```
try:
    time.sleep(1)
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "More than 3000 results")]')))
    driver.quit()
except:
    print("Did not see More than 3000 results text")

Continue with script...
```

```
try:
    time.sleep(1)
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[contains(text(), "The search returned zero results")]')))
    driver.quit()
except:
    print("Did not see The search returned zero results text")

Continue with script...
```

Comment: Please explain more. What error you get? when you tried this code? how the html code looks like? dont add screenshot of code.

Comment: My reply is too long so I am editing my main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following `xpath` which will return both the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[normalize-space(.)="More than 3000 results" or normalize-space(.)="The search returned zero results"]')))
```

OR you can use below xpath as well.#

```
//*[contains(text(),"More than 3000 results") or contains(text(),"The search returned zero results")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks pretty correct. Can you post the errors you are receiving and maybe the html you are working with so that we can test it too?

The only thing I can think of from looking at the code is that the quotes inside the string might be messing things up. I normally escape all the quotes inside the string when using selenium, so maybe you could try that. So your xpath string becomes:

```
'//*[contains(text(), \"More than 3000 results\")]'
```

Actually, from your edit, I think the issue is that it just doesn't exist in python. Take a look [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/7121) and [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/7406). I think the current syntax you are using only exists in Java.

Comment: I edited my initial post showing the syntax error from the first example. Example two and three are just ignored and the script just continues.